# How to increase performance of a report in Cognos TM1?

Tags: cognos-tm1

While user generate report in TM1 web, how the reprots performance be increased?
What are the various ways  of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Mainly by suppressing zeros and optimizing the subsets you use on rows/columns.